# can http://productionsite.com links direct to http://localhost/productionsite in some sort of wamp setting

Tags: php, wamp

I like to use absolute paths in most of my apps.

I am using a wamp server to develop on for the first time and was wondering if there is a way to spoof the production path to the localhost path

so even though the code reads

```
 include('mysite.com/file.php')
```

i would like the wamp server to deliver

```
localhost/mysite/file.php
```

How I can do that?

Comment: Why you want to use absolutes paths ?

Comment: i think it is much cleaner than ../../../../folder/file.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, or define yourself where a `$root_path`.

This way you can `include "$root_path/path/to/file.php"` and it will work everywhere.

Comment: so on the local machine this gives me C:/wamp/www/.. the root for the actual project is c:/wamp/www/spt. on the .com it gives me home/user/public_html, and i need it to be /... is there a setting i need to do or should i modify the string provided by $_SERVER['document_root']

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume this is because if you try to go to `mysite.com`, it never loads, due to how you set up your router or something.

I'm also going to assume you are on Windows, because you said WAMP.

---

What you need to do is modify your `hosts` file (if you aren't sure how, see [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350)).

Add the following code to the end of it:

```
127.0.0.1   mysite.com
```

and save it, obviously. (The four spaces are supposed to be a tab character, but StackOverflow doesn't let me post them here.)

Either that, or set up DNS recursion, which is more challenging and router-specific.

Comment: i am using the wamp to develop the site before loading to mysite.com.. i will check the tutorial, thanks.

Comment: @SmithSmithy I guess I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am developing the app locally, on my machine and testing it using  WAMP as my server setup. when i write the code, i would like to put in the actual site links as if it were running on the .com server so that i do not have to change them from localhost to mysite.com when i am ready upload and make live.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use absolute path is the only solution.

If you do you cast your site and scripts in concrete.